# Expected family size and gender distribution of a given scenario

Tags: probability

A country adopted a policy requiring all couples to continue having children until they had a girl, after which they must stop having children. How many children will the average family have and what will the gender distribution be?

I understand that the gender distribution of the population is $50$% boys and $50$% girls because despite how hard a couple wants to have a girl, they cannot control the outcome of whether the child is a boy or a girl.

However, I did not find a way to obtain how many children the average family will have. The answer says that the average family has $2$ children. Can someone please explain it?

Answer (score 1):

The assumption that a birth is equally likely to produce a girl or not discounts *a lot* of factors but, *meh*, it is a close enough approximation for this problem.

If a family has no boys they will either have a girl in the next birth, or keep trying from there.   So, for families with no girls, the expected number of further births until a girl is always :

$$\mathsf E(N) = \tfrac 12 + \tfrac 12(1+\mathsf E(N))$$

Solve for $\mathsf E(N)$.   This will be the expected number of births until a family obtains a girl.

> We may also observe that with your assumption, the count of births until "success" is by definition a *Geometrically distributed* random variable, and the expectation of such is well known.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about showing that the average family will have two children.

Perhaps the simplest way of explaining it is that every family will have exactly one girl.  Since as you mentioned the population will be half boys and half girls, the families must average one boy per family to end up with this $50/50$ distribution.  Therefore, the average family will have two children.